# Clickonce after asynchrone call

Tags: javascript, clickonce

When directly opening a clickonce application after a user event it works. When there is some asynchrone code it fails. I found this [site](http://vcsjones.com/2012/12/12/clickonce-only-working-in-medium-low-security-for-internet-explorer/) describing the problem exactly, but not supplying a solution. Any idea? Changing the browser settings is not a option.

```
//Following works:
$('#buttonId').click(function() {
    window.location.href = 'path/to/clickonce/app.application';
});
//Following fails:
$('#buttonId').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        ...
        success: function () {
            window.location.href = 'path/to/clickonce/app.application';
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Looks fine, still try this once, $('#buttonId').on('click',function() {